# Mule ESB restarting itself

Tags: mysql, memory-management, mule

I'm having an issue with my Mule application.

I'm running my Mule application on an Amazon Micro Instance, the app starts to insert massive data in a mysql database, suddenly mule application restarts itself leaving this in the log:

```
JVM exited unexpectedly.
JVM exited in response to signal SIGKILL 
9
...
...
...
Startup failed: Timed out waiting for signal from JVM.
JVM did not exit on request, terminated
JVM exited on its own while waiting to kill the application.
JVM exited in response to signal SIGKILL 
9
...
...
...
```

Could it be a memory of CPU amount issue because of the low resources offered by the Micro Instance? If not, what would be a good solution?

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13104630/387927: can you try the proposed solution?

Comment: Any progress on this? Was it really a OOM issue?

Answer (score 1):

probably startup is too slow. Try to update timeout at conf/wrapper.conf:

```
# Increase the default startup timeout so that the JVM has enough
# time to download the required jars on a slow connection
wrapper.startup.timeout=1200
```

Comment: This can only happen if Mule comes up slowly. But it does not belong to the question, cause Mule is already up'n running and will be killed under high load..

Answer (score 0):

Mule process will be controlled by the `wrapper` which also monitor the process. There can be different situations. For example the `JVM` will not answer under high load to the ping the `wrapper` has sent. The default configuration will kill (`kill -9`) the Mule process and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar log error. Causes were:

- incorrect jvm system properties: -M ...

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/mule-app-properties-system

- ram less than 512m
- ram more than hardware limit
- java ram: xmx xms incorrect

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely memory issue. You do not have enough memory.

Since your memory is limited - optimize your solution to use streams instead of keeping values in memory/variables.