# Can one install yesod with 768 MB of RAM?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am new to haskell and yesod. I've follow the [quick start guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) to install yesod.

But at the 3rd step, when I run `stack install yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc` command, the CPU usage became 100%, and after a while, it throw an error:

```
~/my-project$ stack install yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc
Cabal-1.22.6.0: configure
Progress: 1/108
....
[19 of 79] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription ( Distribution/PackageDescription.hs, /tmp/stack2919/Cabal-1.22.6.0/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/setup/Distribution/PackageDescription.o )
    ghc: out of memory (requested 2097152 bytes)
```

I also find that other program was been killed (a Node.js server)...

Here is my server information:

```
~/my-project$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2399.996
BogoMIPS:              4799.99
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
```

---

```
~/my-project$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          741M       276M       465M       2.0M       7.2M        68M
-/+ buffers/cache:       201M       540M
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

---

However, I can not find any hardware in yesod's official website.

Comment: I've installed yesod sites with only 128M (on archlinux) and runs fine. But you should upload precompiled binaries to your production machine. Read how to deploy Yesod http://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp

Comment: Try to add swap space: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13106205/1651941

Comment: @josejuan Is the compile time very long ? I've try the quick start guide on my Macbook air 2013 too. The compile/build time is really long. Is this normal ?

Comment: As Sibi suggests, add swap. The linked answer suggests 1GB of swap, but you might want that to be 2GB. For good measure, chown the swapfile to root and chmod it to 600. As josejuan suggests, in the long run you may want binary deployment simply because it's faster, puts less responsibility on your server nodes making deployment to multiple servers less time-consuming.

Comment: I have a (very simple) Yesod server that I both compile and run on a Raspberry Pi B with only 512 M in total. Of course, that's a 32-bit architecture. I definitely needed extra swap for compiling GHC, and I think also for compiling Yesod. The server itself needs 103 MB right now.

Comment: @user2331095 yes, compile all needed packages may take long time, stack is other recommended (I love it!) tool that minimize compilation time http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README.html